# Variadic Typenames in Template Functions

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I've been toying around with variadic templates for a little while and I've found something that I'd like to do but I don't know whether it is possible or not.

A rough idea of what I'm trying to accomplish is a template class that performs specific operations depending on what type of object is stored instide of it. I'd like to be able to handle inheritance, so a type "Derived" class will be included in the operation that deals with only "Base" object. I've figured out that variadic templates are what I need, I just can't get them to work like I want.

Basically, I'd like to know if you can make a variadic function that accepts a variable number of typenames instead of a variable number of arguments.

Here is what I have so far:

```
template <typename T>
void DoesNotWork()
{
    //Do stuff
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
void DoesNotWork()
{
    //Do stuff

    DoesNotWork<Args...>();
}
```

However, because both functions have the same number of arguments, it throws an "ambiguous function reference" error. If I remove the top function, the last recursive call tries to call "DoesNotWork<>()" which does not have a definition.

How would I go about doing this? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to disambiguate between the two functions when `Args` is empty.

What you need is:

```
template <typename T>
void DoesNotWork()
{
    //Do stuff
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Args>
void DoesNotWork()
{
    //Do stuff

    DoesNotWork<T2, Args...>();
}
```